# Combining a looping listing query with specific parameters query

Tags: graphql, meetup

I have two separate working calls, defined below, which I am trying to figure out how to combine. The schema is specific to [Meetup API,](https://www.meetup.com/api/schema/#graphQl-schema) but I think general GraphQL-fu can help here!

- Call 1 gets a list of `N` Event IDs

```
query($query:String!,$lat: Float!,$lon:Float!,$radius:Int!) {
    keywordSearch(filter: {query: $query,lat: $lat, lon: $lon, radius:$radius source:EVENTS, eventType:PHYSICAL}) {
      count 
      edges{
        node{
          id
        }
      } 
    }
}
```

As a sample query:
`{"query":"knitting ","lat":37.774929,"lon":-122.419418,"radius":50}`

Here are the results (knitting meetups are not that common in San Francisco):

```
{
  "data": {
    "keywordSearch": {
      "count": 3,
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "281538648!chp"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "281467251!chp"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "281455979!chp"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- Call 2 gets additional Event information from the `id` returned in Call 1

```
  query($eventId: ID) {
    event(id: $eventId) {
      ... bare_event
    }
  }
  
  fragment bare_event on Event{
    title 
      dateTime
      eventUrl
      onlineVenue{
        type
        url
      }
      venue{
                ... bare_venue
      }
  }
  
  fragment bare_venue on Venue{
        id
        name
        address
  }
```

So, for example, grabbing the first ID from Call1, using `{"eventId":"281538648!chp"}`, we get

```
{
  "data": {
    "event": {
      "title": "Monday Knitting Meetup (Mountain View)",
      "dateTime": "2021-10-25T19:00-07:00",
      "eventUrl": "https://www.meetup.com/scv-knitters/events/281538648",
      "onlineVenue": null,
      "venue": {
        "id": "25006220",
        "name": "Panera Bread (YET ANOTHER PANERA!!)",
        "address": "1035 El Monte Ave"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How do we have that Call 2 verbose event information included in call 1, along with each event ID?**

I think the point of GraphQL is so that I would not have to make `N+1` queries for fetching additional information for `N` items related from a search list (I'm new!)

*How do you combine these two calls into one query, so that in additional to pulling only the event ID, I can also pull other event information, for each of the search listings?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query and how to fetch the data

```
query ($query: String!, $lat: Float!, $lon: Float!, $radius: Int!) {
  keywordSearch(
    filter: {query: $query, lat: $lat, lon: $lon, radius: $radius, source: EVENTS, eventType: PHYSICAL}
  ) {
    count
    edges {
      node {
        id
        result {
          ... on Event {
            title
            dateTime
            eventUrl
            onlineVenue {
              type
              url
            }
            venue {
              id
              name
              address
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "query": "knitting ",
  "lat": 37.774929,
  "lon": -122.419418,
  "radius": 50
}
```

Comment: Ah, so the concept I was missing is `union` - basically `SearchNode` contains a result of type Event `... on Event {`?

Comment: That’s correct. A union type means the type can be any of the types in the definition. In order to specify what fields you want from a type you use an inline fragment. This is a way of saying: if you find a type Event use these fields. You can repeat this for all types in the union or just the one you are interested

Comment: Once you are happy with the answer. Accept it so it's closed

Comment: Thanks! Super useful to know union in GraphQL is quite different than SQL!